# How to interpret morphisms of field extensions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, intuition

In field theory the following definition is (as far as I can tell) standard:

> Let $K$ be a field. Given two extensions $K\subset L$ and $K\subset L'$, we say that they are $K$-homomorphic if there exists a field homomorphism $\varphi:L\to L'$ such that $\varphi$ is the identity on $K$.

I have some trouble with this definition. Namely, it makes sense to me when $K,L,L'$ all happen to  simultaneously be subfields of some "universal field" $U$ where everything is taking place (e.g. extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$), but when it's about "abstract" extensions, without reference to a common enveloping field, the technicalities start to pester me (e.g. how is it possible for the same set $K$ to be a subset of two other unrelated sets? where is it all "taking place"?). I tried then to re-interpret this definition in greater explicitness, considering instead of literal inclusion $K\subset L$ homomorphisms $i:K\to L$ and $i':K\to L'$ (which are automatically injective) and calling $\varphi$ an extension morphism if $i'\circ\operatorname{id}_K=\varphi\circ i$ (the diagram commutes). This then leads to its own complications, because now that $K$ is not a literal subfield of $L$, stuff like $K(S)$ needs to be reinterpreted and some basic lemmas feel more complicated as a result. But then if I switch back and consider something "concrete" like $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$, somehow it's not unnatural to think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as existing in two different places simultaneously. I know that for algebraic extensions of $K$ you can think of it all as taking place in an algebraically closed field $C$ containing $K$ (e.g. how it is with $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$), but then I start wondering how that all depends on the way $K$ might be embedded in $C$ and how many embeddings might there be and so on.

That's not to say that fields have me completely confused - when the lines of inclusion are clearly delineated, I don't have any problems. For example, everything related to things happening  in the context of a single pair $K\subset L$ (algebraicity, separability, degree, etc.) is clear to me. I also have no trouble with such pairs interacting, e.g. where you consider things like $K\subset L,K'\subset L'$, an isomorphism $\varphi:K\to K'$ and its various extensions to $L$. It's when the lines start to get blurry (e.g. in the previous setting, when $\varphi$ is taken to be $\operatorname{id}_K$) that I start to get confused.

Anyway, sorry about the ramble. The long and short of it is, field extensions and their morphisms are a bit of a salad in my head and I was hoping to get some explanations on how to interpret it all.

Comment: I think that thinking categorically in terms of inclusion arrows is useful. Also, for the extension to even be an extension, such inclusions / subset relations must exist.

Comment: @FShrike you mean it's better to think of homomorphisms $i:K\to L$ rather than subfields $K\subset L$?

Comment: Field extensions are (conceptually) better understood as objects in a category. It's rather exceptional than normal to have the big elephant in the room (the algebraic closure in this case) constructible. For example, the category of finite extensions doesn't admit this elephant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but when it's about "abstract" extensions, without reference to a common enveloping field, the technicalities start to pester me (e.g. how is it possible for the same set $K$ to be a subset of two other unrelated sets? where is it all "taking place"?).

You can write everything down in terms of homomorphisms (which are automatically injective) $i : K \to L$ and $i' : K \to L'$ as you suggest. Then a $K$-homomorphism is a homomorphism $\varphi : L \to L'$ such that $\varphi \circ i = i'$ as you say (there is no need to explicitly compose with the identity morphism). I don't know what you mean by "stuff like $K(S)$ needs to be reinterpreted" but everything continues to work just fine.

There is no issue with thinking of $K$ as literally a subfield of every field extension of $K$; the point of the definition of a $K$-homomorphism is exactly to guarantee that you don't run into any trouble by doing this, because the definition forces all computations done in all such copies of $K$ to be consistent (as long as you only ever move from one field to another via a $K$-homomorphism).

> But then if I switch back and consider something "concrete" like $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}\subset\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-2)$, somehow it's not unnatural to think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as existing in two different places simultaneously.

For $\mathbb{Q}$ the condition is automatic; that is, if $L, L'$ are two field extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ then every homomorphism $L \to L'$ is automatically a $\mathbb{Q}$-homomorphism. This is a good exercise.

The condition wouldn't be automatic already for $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$, say, and would then need to be checked.

> I know that for algebraic extensions of $K$ you can think of it all as taking place in an algebraically closed field $C$ containing $K$ (e.g. how it is with $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$), but then I start wondering how that all depends on the way $K$ might be embedded in $C$ and how many embeddings might there be and so on.

It's good that you're worrying about this and the answer is to not try to embed everything into a common field, it's not necessary and ultimately makes things more confusing because you're making extra choices you don't need to.

Comment: Thanks. I should've worded things more carefully perhaps, I think what bothers me as much as (or even more than) $K$-homomorphisms is this slightly schizoid view of the same field existing in different places, but not really (or yes really?). In some cases (like for extensions of $\mathbb Q$ I mentioned above) this feels natural and inoffensive, but in other situations it starts to bother me.

Comment: @V.Ch.: here's a similar but simpler example of this phenomenon, you can see whether it bothers you or not. In every field there are these elements that we call $1, 2, 3, \dots$; does it bother you that, say, $3 \in \mathbb{Q}$ is not literally the same element as $3 \in \mathbb{R}$ or $3 \in \mathbb{C}$ or for that matter $3 \in \mathbb{F}_q$? The resolution here is that every ring (and in particular every field) admits a canonical homomorphism $\mathbb{Z} \to R$ so every ring homomorphism is a $\mathbb{Z}$-homomorphism.

Comment: This is a good example and you're right, it doesn't bother me ($n\in\mathbb Z$ has a unique well-defined "meaning" in every unital ring)! So I should think about different $K$-extensions and $K$-homomorphisms the same way (elements of $K$ have well-defined "meaning" in two fields $L,L'$, so we can consider homomorphisms that preserve this)?

Comment: @V.Ch.: yes, that's right. The "meaning" is provided by the homomorphisms $i : K \to L$ and this meaning is "consistent" between different $K$-extensions precisely because we use $K$-homomorphisms to pass between them. So, for example, if $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ and I'm doing some computation involving multiple $K$-extensions $L, L'$ and at some point I refer to $\sqrt{2}$, you know I mean the image of $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ under one of the inclusions $i, i' : \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \to L, L'$.

Comment: Thank you! On a related note, is there a reference on fields/Galois theory you could recommend? One that is thorough and not hand-wavey, that goes into detail w/o just concentrating on finite extensions and characteristic 0?

Comment: I don't have a single text I really love. Milne's *Fields and Galois Theory* looks good although I haven't read it (https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/FTe6.pdf), and K. Conrad has some great expository papers here: https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/